# How to get a dataflow job's step details using Java Beam SDK?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm using Java Beam SDK for my dataflow job, and `com.google.api.services.dataflow.model.Job` class gives details about a particular job. However, it doesn't provide any method/property to get dataflow step information such as **Elements Added**, **Estimated Size** etc.

[image]

Below is the code I'm using to get the job's information,

```
PipelineResult result = p.run();        
String jobId = ((DataflowPipelineJob) result).getJobId();
DataflowClient client = DataflowClient.create(options);
Job job = client.getJob(jobId);
```

I'm looking for something like,

```
job.getSteps("step name").getElementsAdded();
job.getSteps("step name").getEstimatedSize();
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The [`SinkMetrics`](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.1.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/metrics/SinkMetrics.html) class provides a `bytesWritten()` method and a `elementsWritten()` method. In addition, the [`SourceMetrics`](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.1.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/metrics/SourceMetrics.html) class provides an `elementsRead()` and a `bytesRead()` method.

If you use the classes in the `org.apache.beam.sdk.metrics` package to query for these metrics and filter by step, you should be able to get the underlying metrics for the stop (i.e., elements read).

I would add that if you're willing to look outside of the Beam Java SDK, since you're running on Google Cloud Dataflow you can use the [`Google Dataflow API`](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/reference/rest/) In particular, you can use [`projects.jobs.getMetrics`](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/reference/rest/v1b3/projects.jobs/getMetrics) to fetch the detailed metrics for the job including the number of elements written/read. You will need to do some parsing of the metrics as there are hundreds of metrics for even a simple job, but the underlying data you're looking for is present via this API call (I just tested).